# Найти количество чисел от 1 до 1000 в которых есть цифра 3

Tags: javascript, математика

Помогите пожалуйста написать код на js, который ищет количество чисел от 1 до 1000 в которых есть цифра 3. Желательно с помощью остатка от деления.Пытался решить так, но числа типа 931 не видит.

```
let count = 0;
for(var i = 1; i<=1000;i++) {
if (i%10==3 || i%100===30 || i%1000===300 || ~~((i/1000)*10)/10==0.3 || ~~((i/100)*10)/10==0.3){
count++;
document.write(i+"<br/>")}
}
alert(count)
```

Comment: На этом сайте, чтобы вопрос не заминусовали и закрыли, необходимо дополнить его собственными попытками справиться с проблемой. [**Аргументация, почему**](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/). Спасибо.

Comment: А почему желательно с помощью остатка от деления?

Comment: @Эникейщик Потому что так в задании написано, очевидимо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let count = 0, num = 1000;
const check3 = num => num%10 === 3 || num > 9 && check3(Math.floor(num/10));
while(count += check3(num--), num);
console.log(count);

// 931 видит - 
console.log(check3(931))
```